# Pass a variable from blade to route and from there to another route

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-routing

I know there must be simpler way than I have imagined it so im going to ask here.

I want to pass `$exam->id` from here (when you click on the start test)

```
@foreach($category->exams as $exam)
    <tr>
        <td>{{$exam->id}}</td>
        <td>{{$exam->title}}</td>
        <td>od {{$exam->start_date}} do {{$exam->end_date}}</td>
        <td class="center"><span class="badge">{{$exam->number_of_points}}</span></td>
        <td class="center"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i> Start test</a></td>
    </tr>
@endforeach()
```

This should use this route and pass that variable

```
 Route::get('exam','ExamController@create'); // this is where i dont know how to set route to pass to another one
```

ExamController

```
 public function create() {

    return View::make('exam.index');
}
```

And finnaly when user clicks on submit, it sends that $exam_id to ajax to show that exam

```
{{ Form::open(['data-remote', 'method' => 'GET', 'route' => ['exam_data',$exam_id]]) }}
    <div class="exam-name">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group exam">   
        Click Start to start the test!
   </div>

    <div class="form-group">

        {{ Form::submit('Start', ['class' => 'btn btn-default','id'=>'btn-next-question', 'data-confirm']) }}

   </div>

 {{Form::close()}}
```

Route for submit button

```
Route::get('exam/{id}',['as' => 'exam_data', 'uses' => 'ExamController@getExambyNumber']);
```

Everything works fine when I put random exam id number like 1 instead of `$exam_id` on that form I just don't know how would I pass that. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Store the information within the session. Then it will be available on all requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out first what i did was change Start Test to pass an array to Route

```
 <td class="center"><a href="{{ URL::route('exam_id', array('id'=>$exam->id)) }}"><i   class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i> Start Test</a></td>
```

Exam Route

```
Route::get('exam',['as' => 'exam_id', 'uses' => 'ExamController@create']);
```

which in controller looks like

```
public function create()
{

   $exam_id = Input::get('id');
   return View::make('exam.index', array('exam_id' => $exam_id));
}
```

And the rest of the code is the same.